# SQL Server Generate Script to Alter Data Type

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im using SQl Server management studio, trying to change a Datatype from char(8) to char(10) however it won't let me actually "save" the generate script (I have to send the script to someone off site)

Is there a way to do this in SQL Management Studio (it's 2008R2 for the actual database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name new_datatype nullability
```

Plese be careful, add `null` or `not null` to the end of sentence in replace of `nullability` as this may change in other case

Just to show how nullability can annoy: [sqlfiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12691)

Answer (score 0):

SSMS can generate the change script in a database diagram. Simply add your table to a new diagram, make your change, and, without saving, then hit the "Generate Change Script" button (or menu item).

Or you can write the correct `alter table` statement from scratch.

Comment: When you right click on the table you can do "Generate Script as" :"Drop and Create table to query". Would that work (I can just change the char(8) to char(10) in the query window...and then save it?

Comment: @Mercfh That works only if you're OK with losing any data that was originally in the table.